# Handling multidimentional array in java script is not working

Tags: javascript

```
function split(str)
{
var array = str.split(';');
var test[][] = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var arr = array[i].split(',');

        for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        {

            test[i][j]=arr[j];
        }
    }
}
```

onchange="split('1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;a,b,c;d,e,f;g,h,i')"

it was not working. i need to split this string to 6*3 multi dimentional array

Comment: Javascript does not support multidimensional arrays! In javascript you can only declare onedimensional array each element of which contains other onedimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var array[][] = new Array()` is not valid syntax for declaring arrays.  Javascript arrays are one dimensional leaving you to nest them.  Which means you need to insert a new array into each slot yourself before you can start appending to it.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/ShWGB/

```
function split(str) {
    var lines = str.split(';');
    var test = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (typeof test[i] === 'undefined') {
            test[i] = [];
        }

        var line = lines[i].split(',');
        for(var j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
            test[i][j] = line[j];
        }
    }

    return test;
}

console.log(split('a,b,c;d,e,f'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`var test[][]` is an invalid javascript syntax.

To create a 2D array, which is an array of array, just declare your array and push arrays into it.

Something like this:

```
 var myArr = new Array(10);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myArr[i] = new Array(20);
  }
```

I'll let you apply this to your problem. Also, I don't like the name of your function, try to use something different from the standards, to avoid confusion when you read your code days or months from now.

Comment: There is almost never a reason to use `new Array()` and even less of a reason to use `new Array(integer)`

Comment: To expand on what Alex said, use `[]` instead of `new Array()`. And you don't need to provide a size because JS arrays are dynamic so regardless of the current length of the array you can always add new elements at the end. (Note that `[10]` doesn't create an array with 10 elements, it creates an array with one element that has the value 10.)

Comment: I'm aware of that thank you. About using `new Array()` I was just trying to keep the look&feel of the OP code, and about the integer, I was trying to explain how arrays work, because it seems that the OP was lacking understanding. However, you are completely right, `[]` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

```
function split(str)
{
    var array = str.split(';'),
        length = array.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) array[i] = array[i].split(',');

    return array;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AbXNk/

Answer (score -1):

```
var str='1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;a,b,c;d,e,f;g,h,i';
var arr=str.split(";");
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)arr[i]=arr[i].split(",");
```

Now `arr` is an array with 6 elements and each element contain array with 3 elements.

Accessing element:

```
 alert(arr[4][2]); // letter "f" displayed
```